# Implementing JWT on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt, ruby-on-rails-5, token

I am having a problem while trying to implement devise jwt.
This is my devise user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord  
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :database_authenticatable,
         :jwt_authenticatable,
         jwt_revocation_strategy: JwtBlacklist 
end
```

And this is my blacklist.rb model.

```
class JwtBlacklist < ApplicationRecord
include Devise::JWT::RevocationStrategies::Blacklist

self.table_name = 'jwt_blacklist'
end
```

This is what i am getting.

```
Caused by:
NameError: uninitialized constant User::JwtBlacklist
```

Hope you could help me with this I am new on Rails. 
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're calling your model `JwtBlacklist` then the filename *must* be `jwt_blacklist.rb` so that the auto-loader can find it. Right now the name implies the model is called `Blacklist`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help. That was the solution.
Have an excellent day friend.

Answer (score 17):

Note that `include Devise::JWT::RevocationStrategies::Blacklist` had been replaced with `include Devise::JWT::RevocationStrategies::Denylist` according to `devise-jwt` documentation.

Comment: That did help me a bit